# Declare a namespace inside Policy in API Management Service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am working on API Management service. I want to set Authorization Header in API.
I have used Set-Header policy & in Value tag, I need to generate **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory** Authentication object.
But I am not able to add Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory namespace inside the policy.
I need to make sure is this possible to add **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory** namespace inside Policy Expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, policy expressions allow a [subset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#CLRTypes) of .NET Framework.